# How could we enable the global header bar on the top of the org landing page

Tags: configuration, org

As you can see the toolbar in the below screenshot
How could we config it?
Thanks
[image: inline]

## Update

After enabling the community, then followed by going to the profile and enable this option.

[image: inline]

Comment: I updated your question title, replaced `tooltip` with `header`, as tooltip implied that the bar will only appear on mouse-hover or similar event, which is not **true**. This bar stays there as the header if communities are enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [global header](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_global_header.htm&type=5) in salesforce [communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_resources.htm&type=5) and it appears when you enable [salesforce communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_overview.htm&type=5).

[image]

> **Important**
>   The global header is visible only in Salesforce orgs using Salesforce Classic. Salesforce orgs using Lightning Experience can use the App Launcher.

Comment: Sorry for any typos or late edits, posting from mobile.

Comment: I activated communities, but the header is still missing not showing

Comment: Need go to system permission and check it. Thanks ~

Comment: Users will need to have **view global header** permission. Plz check the article related to global header